# how to get listview and tabview effect using phonegap?

Tags: iphone, android, listview, cordova, tabview

i have developed an android application which has listview and tabview.sue to crossplatform necessity i am creating the application with the help of phonegap. is it possible to have the native listview and tabview using html and css??? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot have the native view, but you can fake it.
You can make the design look like the native list and tab view.

If you want you can make that on every platform and switch between them using javascript.
Maby a UI framework like sencha touch already incorporates that?

Succes,
Erik

Comment: how to fake that? is it possible with html and css? let me know whether i can use sencha touch and phonegap in my application?

Comment: It is designing it just like that, so not using the native design features itself. You can use sencha in phonegap just like jquery mobile, e.o.